# How can I define the title that is used in the node tree? My own node types are always displayed as "Untitled"

Tags: neoscms

I am using neos version beta 1.0.2.
I have a custom package in neos installation.
But when i create new content elements it always shows "untitled" in node tree.
Its very difficult to differentiate content elements if the tree  title is same.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `\TYPO3\TYPO3CR\Domain\Model\DefaultNodeLabelGenerator` and implement the interface for your content types.

Comment: But this Untitled heading will not come when i add content from editor window(content canvas).
It only happens if i click on Plus button (create new) in Structure tree

What may be the issue?